# r gsub regex keep only [A-z0-9_] but ^ also remains

Tags: r, regex

I want to keep a string that is only letters, numbers or underscore. However when I use

```
gsub('[^A-z0-9_]',"","some lab value (x10^9L)")
```

I get

```
[1] "somelabvaluex10^9L"
```

Which is unexpected since `^` character is kept in the string.
I tried different options without any luck.

Comment: `[A-z]` matches `[`, ``\``, `]`, `^`, `_`, `\``, and the English letters so the result **is** expected. You wanted to use `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` or just `\W`: `gsub('\\W+','','some lab value (x10^9L)')`, or `gsub('\\W+','','some lab value (x10^9L)', perl=TRUE)` or `gsub('[^_[:alnum:]]+','','some lab value (x10^9L)')`

Comment: So `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` should work.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: And I didn't know this `^` is called caret. Otherwise I would have found the answer...